# iPhone MKMapView Annotation Clustering

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, markerclusterer

I've got quite a lot of pins to put on my map so I think it would be a nice idea to cluster those annotations. I'm not really sure how to achieve this on iPhone, I was able to work something out with google maps and some javascript examples. But iPhone uses its mkmapview and I have no idea how to cluster annotations in there.

Any ideas or frameworks that you know and are good? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/stars?direction=desc&sort=created&q=cluster

Comment: @brian.clear: well you queried link show nothing.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Well, it shows a search result to your personal stared github projects. In my case I was lucky to find https://github.com/choefele/CCHMapClusterController and https://github.com/thoughtbot/TBAnnotationClustering

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this is a very common problem and i needed a solution i have wrote a custom subclass of MKMapView which supports clustering. Then i made it available open source! You can get it here: https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView.

It manages the clustering of the annotations and you can handle their views by yourself.
You don't have to do anything but to copy the `OCMapView` folder to your project, create a `MKMapView` in your nib and set its class to `OCMapView`. (Or create and delegate it in code like a regular `MKMapView`)

Comment: The class mentioned in this answer has been abandoned by the OP. Last change is over a year ago.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer. Well it kinda was. I currently working on a swift port. :)

Answer (score 40):

You don't necessarily need to use a 3rd party framework because since iOS 4.2, MKMapView has a method called `- (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect` which you can use to do your clustering.

Check out the WWDC11 Session video '[Visualizing Information Geographically with MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=111)'. About half way through it explains how to do it. But I'll summarize the concept for you:

- Use Two maps (*second map is never added to the view hierarchy*)
- Second map contains all annotations (*again, it's never drawn*)
- Divide map area into a grid of squares
- Use `-annotationsInMapRect` method to get annotation data from
  invisible map
- Visible map builds its annotations from this data from invisible map

[image]

Comment: where can i find the code demo-ed in this WWDC video

Comment: I implemented this and it's OK...other clustering algorithms like [quadtree](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps) or maybe [optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) probably display better but would be more complex to implement

Comment: demo code is available at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I downloaded the demo code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html
but I found that when I am rotating and zooming the map randomly it got stuck. please if you have any other demo then help me.

Comment: Here is the rotating problem solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36388947/1672575

Answer (score 16):

Fortunately, you don't need 3rd party framework's anymore. iOS 11 has native clustering support.

You need to implement [`mapView:clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/2867923-mapview?language=objc) method.

Get more details in the Apple example: https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/MapKit-Sample.zip

Comment: How do you disable it in runtime? do you know how?

Answer (score 8):

By using Apple demo code it's easy to implement clustering concept in our code.  [Reference link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html)

Simply we can use following code for the Clustering

Steps to implement clustering

**Step1 :** The important thing is for clustering we use two mapviews(allAnnotationsMapView, ), One is for reference(allAnnotationsMapView).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *allAnnotationsMapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

In **viewDidLoad**

```
    _allAnnotationsMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

**Step2 :** Add all annotations to the _allAnnotationsMapView, In below _photos are the annotations array.

```
        [_allAnnotationsMapView addAnnotations:_photos];
        [self updateVisibleAnnotations];
```

**Step3 :** Add below methods for clustering, in this PhotoAnnotation is the custom annotation.
**MapViewDelegate methods**

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    [self updateVisibleAnnotations];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

    for (MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
        if (![annotationView.annotation isKindOfClass:[PhotoAnnotation class]]) {
            continue;
        }

        PhotoAnnotation *annotation = (PhotoAnnotation *)annotationView.annotation;

        if (annotation.clusterAnnotation != nil) {
            // animate the annotation from it's old container's coordinate, to its actual coordinate
            CLLocationCoordinate2D actualCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D containerCoordinate = annotation.clusterAnnotation.coordinate;

            // since it's displayed on the map, it is no longer contained by another annotation,
            // (We couldn't reset this in -updateVisibleAnnotations because we needed the reference to it here
            // to get the containerCoordinate)
            annotation.clusterAnnotation = nil;

            annotation.coordinate = containerCoordinate;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

**clustering Handling methods**

```
    - (id<MKAnnotation>)annotationInGrid:(MKMapRect)gridMapRect usingAnnotations:(NSSet *)annotations {

    // first, see if one of the annotations we were already showing is in this mapRect
    NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];
    NSSet *annotationsForGridSet = [annotations objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        BOOL returnValue = ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:obj]);
        if (returnValue)
        {
            *stop = YES;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }];

    if (annotationsForGridSet.count != 0) { 
        return [annotationsForGridSet anyObject];
    }

    // otherwise, sort the annotations based on their distance from the center of the grid square,
    // then choose the one closest to the center to show
    MKMapPoint centerMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(gridMapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(gridMapRect));
    NSArray *sortedAnnotations = [[annotations allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        MKMapPoint mapPoint1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(((id<MKAnnotation>)obj1).coordinate);
        MKMapPoint mapPoint2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(((id<MKAnnotation>)obj2).coordinate);

        CLLocationDistance distance1 = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mapPoint1, centerMapPoint);
        CLLocationDistance distance2 = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mapPoint2, centerMapPoint);

        if (distance1 < distance2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if (distance1 > distance2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    PhotoAnnotation *photoAnn = sortedAnnotations[0];
    NSLog(@"lat long %f %f", photoAnn.coordinate.latitude, photoAnn.coordinate.longitude);

    return sortedAnnotations[0];
}

- (void)updateVisibleAnnotations {

    // This value to controls the number of off screen annotations are displayed.
    // A bigger number means more annotations, less chance of seeing annotation views pop in but decreased performance.
    // A smaller number means fewer annotations, more chance of seeing annotation views pop in but better performance.
    static float marginFactor = 2.0;

    // Adjust this roughly based on the dimensions of your annotations views.
    // Bigger numbers more aggressively coalesce annotations (fewer annotations displayed but better performance).
    // Numbers too small result in overlapping annotations views and too many annotations on screen.
    static float bucketSize = 60.0;

    // find all the annotations in the visible area + a wide margin to avoid popping annotation views in and out while panning the map.
    MKMapRect visibleMapRect = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];
    MKMapRect adjustedVisibleMapRect = MKMapRectInset(visibleMapRect, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.width, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.height);

    // determine how wide each bucket will be, as a MKMapRect square
    CLLocationCoordinate2D leftCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointZero toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D rightCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(bucketSize, 0) toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    double gridSize = MKMapPointForCoordinate(rightCoordinate).x - MKMapPointForCoordinate(leftCoordinate).x;
    MKMapRect gridMapRect = MKMapRectMake(0, 0, gridSize, gridSize);

    // condense annotations, with a padding of two squares, around the visibleMapRect
    double startX = floor(MKMapRectGetMinX(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double startY = floor(MKMapRectGetMinY(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double endX = floor(MKMapRectGetMaxX(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double endY = floor(MKMapRectGetMaxY(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;

    // for each square in our grid, pick one annotation to show
    gridMapRect.origin.y = startY;
    while (MKMapRectGetMinY(gridMapRect) <= endY) {
        gridMapRect.origin.x = startX;

        while (MKMapRectGetMinX(gridMapRect) <= endX) {
            NSSet *allAnnotationsInBucket = [self.allAnnotationsMapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];
            NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];

            // we only care about PhotoAnnotations
            NSMutableSet *filteredAnnotationsInBucket = [[allAnnotationsInBucket objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                return ([obj isKindOfClass:[PhotoAnnotation class]]);
            }] mutableCopy];

            if (filteredAnnotationsInBucket.count > 0) {
                PhotoAnnotation *annotationForGrid = (PhotoAnnotation *)[self annotationInGrid:gridMapRect usingAnnotations:filteredAnnotationsInBucket];

                [filteredAnnotationsInBucket removeObject:annotationForGrid];

                // give the annotationForGrid a reference to all the annotations it will represent
                annotationForGrid.containedAnnotations = [filteredAnnotationsInBucket allObjects];

                [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationForGrid];

                for (PhotoAnnotation *annotation in filteredAnnotationsInBucket) {
                    // give all the other annotations a reference to the one which is representing them
                    annotation.clusterAnnotation = annotationForGrid;
                    annotation.containedAnnotations = nil;

                    // remove annotations which we've decided to cluster
                    if ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:annotation]) {
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D actualCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                            annotation.coordinate = annotation.clusterAnnotation.coordinate;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
                            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }

            gridMapRect.origin.x += gridSize;
        }

        gridMapRect.origin.y += gridSize;
    }
}
```

By following above steps we can achieve clustering on mapview, it is not necessary to use any third party code or framework. Please check the [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html) here. Please let me know if you have any doubts on this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at ADClusterMapView ? https://github.com/applidium/ADClusterMapView

It does precisely just this.

Comment: I was very disappointed about this project. Make sure to read all the unsolved GitHub issues before doing too many changes in your code to support it. I didn't and wish I had...

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to clustering pins, just showing its number. The following one
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/qtree-objc fits my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I recently forked off of ADClusterMapView mentioned in another answer and resolved many, if not all, of the issues associated with the project. It's a kd-tree algorithm and animates the clustering.

It's available open source here https://github.com/ashare80/TSClusterMapView

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this framework (XMapView.framework); it now supports iOS 8.

This framework doesn't need you to change your current project structure and it can directly be used to your MKMapView. There is a zip file. It gives you an example to cluster 200 pins at once. After I tested it in an iPod I found it is very smooth.

http://www.xuliu.info/xMapView.html

This library supports:

1. clustering different categories
2. clustering all categories
3. setting up your own cluster radius and so on
4. hide or show a certain of categories
5. individually handle and control each pin in the map

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty cool and well maintained library for both Objective-C and Swift here: https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView

It does clustering really well and also handles large amounts of points due to its integration with [Realm](http://realm.io).