# how to implement clustering as described in WWDC 2011

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

Trying to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/15438440/2839949.
The video is saying that there is a sample code available but i can't find it.
Tried following the video but some parts are skipped for "you can find complete code on the sample code".

Can someone explain how to implement the shown method exactly?
Or, alternatively, if Apple's  sample can't be downloaded any more, is there any other reference that demonstrates how to cluster annotations on a MKMapView without any 3rd party frameworks (like in that video)?

Comment: [One of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7842431/643383) to that same question provides a link to an [open source implementation](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView). You don't need to *use* that framework -- you can just look at the source if you want to see how it's done.

Comment: You might want to modify your question to ask how to implement clustering as described in the WWDC session instead of asking for resources, which is usually a quick way to get a question closed. Even better, take a shot at implementing the technique shown in the video yourself, and ask for help here if you run into a problem. The explanation in the video seems pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks, changed it.
The open source implementation - OCMapView, is NOT making any use of the annotationsInMapRect method shown in that video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be found here:

https://github.com/sanchosrancho/Photo-Map

it is based on the WWDC code I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This was added to Apple's sample Code repository around the release of iOS 8, oddly 3+ years after WWDC. Since then it's been updated - you should be able to find it by simply doing a search for "PhotoMap" in the Xcode documentation center.