# Annotation Clustering in iPhone MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I want to use clustering in MKMap but not by using 3rd party framework.
So for that I download the code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html
but I found that when I am rotating and zooming the map randomly it got stuck. if you have any other demo then please help me.

Comment: But its working for me..

Comment: you used `kingpin` 3rd party api.

Comment: Have u tried zooming and rotating continuously ?
I got stuck within a minute.

Comment: @sumit I have seen that,but it's very big library may cause more memory consumption .

Comment: 256KB on hardDisk and does not take lots of memory.

Comment: @sumit I have checked kingpin demo but it didn't work smoothly ,zooming and rotation takes the command little late.

Comment: @Yuyutsu have u checked PhotoMap demo with zooming and rotating?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the problem in that example code too. The existing code doesn't work with maps that can be rotated.

There are two situations that lead to very long or infinite loops.

1. If you rotate the map 180 degrees, you will end up with a situation where the longitude on the left side of the mapView is larger than the longitude on the right side of the mapView. And if `leftCoordinate` is larger than `rightCoordinate`, `gridSize` becomes negative. In the while loops, we increase the origin of the map rect by`gridSize` until it's larger than `endX`/`endY`. But if `gridSize` is negative, the origin will actually become smaller, and the endX condition won't be reached (without an arithmetic underflow).
2. If you rotate the map 90 or 270 degrees, you will end up with two longitudes that are very similar, so gridSize will be very small or even 0, and the loops take a long time (or in case of 0 forever) to complete.

The first problem can be fixed by using `abs()` on `gridSize`. The second problem requires to change the calculation of `rightCoordinate` so it uses point `bucketSize, bucketSize` instead of `bucketSize, 0`. Once that is done we change our current `gridSize` variable to `gridSizeX`, and introduce a `gridSizeY` that uses the .y parts of the MapPoints.

This is the original code:

```
// PhotoMapViewController.m, line 199+

// determine how wide each bucket will be, as a MKMapRect square
CLLocationCoordinate2D leftCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointZero toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
CLLocationCoordinate2D rightCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(bucketSize, 0) toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
double gridSize = MKMapPointForCoordinate(rightCoordinate).x - MKMapPointForCoordinate(leftCoordinate).x;
```

Which will be replaced by this:

```
// determine how wide each bucket will be, as a MKMapRect square
CLLocationCoordinate2D leftCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointZero toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
CLLocationCoordinate2D rightCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(bucketSize, bucketSize) toCoordinateFromView:self.view];

double gridSizeX = fabs(MKMapPointForCoordinate(rightCoordinate).x - MKMapPointForCoordinate(leftCoordinate).x);
double gridSizeY = fabs(MKMapPointForCoordinate(rightCoordinate).y - MKMapPointForCoordinate(leftCoordinate).y);
double gridSize = MAX(gridSizeX, gridSizeY);
```

Answer (score 0):

[MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html) on iOS [CCHMapClusterController](https://github.com/choefele/CCHMapClusterController)

this might helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for library ,but I want to modify Apple's "PhotoMap"demo ,so it doesn't stuck on rotating or zooming.