# cluster in mapkit IOS objective C

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to group annotations in mapkitview with images 
Can any one guide me to get the solution

[image: like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone MKMapView Annotation Clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801015/iphone-mkmapview-annotation-clustering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use clustering libraries, such as this one:
https://github.com/infinum/FBAnnotationClustering