# Add custom annotation then app crashed-ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

i have used this lines of code to add more than **2000** custom annotation on `MkMapView`. Then first received memory warning and app crashed.

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id   <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    //MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
   else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
        static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
        annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapViewForMapScreen dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView) {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        } else {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        }

        MyAnnotation *anno=(MyAnnotation*)annotation;
        tagForAnnotation=(int)anno.tag;

        if (arrayForLatLong.count!=0)
        {
            if ([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"INSTAGRAM"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"instagram.png"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }
            else if([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"TWITTER"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"twt_pin.png"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }

            else if ([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"YOUTUBE"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube.png"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }
            else if ([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"MEETUP"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"meetup_iphone"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }
            else if ([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"FLICKR"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"flikr.png"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }
            else if ([[[arrayForLatLong valueForKey:@"sourceType"]  objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] isEqualToString:@"VK"])
            {
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vk1"];
                annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 22);
            }
        }
        infoButton=[[AsyncImageView alloc]init];
        if ([[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"small"] isEqualToString:@""]){
            if ([[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"medium"] isEqualToString:@""]){
                if ([[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"large"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    [infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }else{
                    [infoButton setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"large"]]];
                }
            }else{
                [infoButton setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"medium"]]];
            }
        }else{
            [infoButton setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"profilePic"] valueForKey:@"small"]]];
        }
        [infoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,30,30)];
        infoButton.layer.cornerRadius=infoButton.frame.size.height/2.0;
        infoButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionForProfileImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        infoButton.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
        infoButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        infoButton.tag=tagForAnnotation;


        //Followed Button:----
        AsyncImageView *followedBtn=[[AsyncImageView alloc]init];
        [followedBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(2,8,17,17)];
        followedBtn.tag=tagForAnnotation;
        if ([[[[arrayForLatLong objectAtIndex:tagForAnnotation] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"isFollowed"] boolValue]==0 ){
            [followedBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            [followedBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [followedBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionForStarImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIView*viewForCallOut=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 50)];
        [viewForCallOut addSubview:infoButton];
        //[viewForCallOut addSubview:followedBtn];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=viewForCallOut;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }


    return nil;
}
```

Please check my code if i have done any mistake then please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You got a memory warning, and it crashed because of it: The ressources of an iDevice is not infinite. In order to "fix" the issue, check if there is no memory leak (with Instruments/Memory Leak), and you may want to avoid that 2000 custom annotations (are they all useful? all visibles?)

Comment: @Larme  Yes they all are useful because i also create on event on custom call out view for all custom annotation with different different information.

Comment: you can load only those notations which are visible as per the map area. Add notations as map zoom.

Comment: @NewStackUser i already zoom map for 5 miles then i need to display all annotations of 5 miles at a time.and i have lots of data to display.what should i do in this condition?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a large number of data points that result in a large number of annotations, a good approach is to cluster the data points and add an annotation for each cluster. As the map is zoomed into a cluster, you replace the annotation representing the cluster with annotations for the data points in the cluster. As you zoom out of a cluster, you replace the annotations representing the data points with an annotation that represents the cluster. This approach reduces the total number of annotations and makes the data easier to comprehend. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801015/iphone-mkmapview-annotation-clustering) and [this post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps) will give you more information about clustering.